# Getting same results from QGIS main canvas and the print layout

Tags: qgis, qgsmapcanvas

I am struggling to get the same results from the main canvas to a new print layout. I have seen a few answers but nothing very specific in the GIS Stack Exchange. I have searched other forums and YouTube as well but I did not find comprehensive answers to the problem.

To put it simple - is there a way to 'clone' the map canvas to a new print layout without getting distorted results? I.e., I had a perfectly looking map in the map canvas (w. labels & symbols) but when I created a new print layout, labels and symbols looked tiny.

Is there a simple (not fiddly) comprehensive answer to getting good results in QGIS?

See screenshots (1st is the main canvas, 2nd is the print layout):

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you edit your question to include screenshots that compare the main canvas to the layout, depicting the differences between the two?

Comment: Hi, I've just re edit it w screenshots. It is not 100% clear but sizes of labels are smaller... the outlined areas inside Zambia are very thick. In general my issue is that a map looks perfectly well in main cavas but when I go to the print layout I always have to tune a fair amount, i..e, give things bigger/smaller size because it looks too small or too big. That makes me modify the main canvas, but then the main canvas looks funny if I want to reuse the map again. I just though there would be a way to literally clone the screen from the main canvas to the print layout. Thanks

Comment: Looks like a dpi issue

Comment: To see how things will look in a layout from the main window they should both be at the same scale, not the same extent.

Comment: Adding to Ian Turton's comment: are you displaying the main canvas and layout on 1) the same monitor, or 2) separate monitors?  If #2, do the two monitors have the same size, resolution and dpi?